# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nProvider <- n

Tags: angularjs

i use angularjs + ionic set up my project。when i use /www catalog visited, the project is running normally, but when i compress the project to /dist catalog, and use /dist catalog visited one of page: #/Mdetails/3023638 , there has a error:

all.min.js:1 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nProvider <- n

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMjsX.png)

but visited other pages it's normal. I don't know if it's because I'm pointing multiple routes to the same page

```js
app.controller('MdetailsCtrl', ["$scope", "$timeout", "$state", "$sce", "$stateParams", "$ionicPopup", "HttpService", "GlobalParamService", function ($scope, $timeout, $state, $sce, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, HttpService, GlobalParamService) {
    ....
}])
```

```html
.state('Mdetails', {
        url: '/Mdetails/:id',
        templateUrl: 'templates/merchant/details.html',
        prefetchTemplate: false,
        controller: 'MdetailsCtrl',
        resolve: loadSequence('MdetailsArgs')
    })
    .state('merchant', {
        url: '/merchant/:id',
        templateUrl: 'templates/merchant/details.html',
        prefetchTemplate: false,
        controller: 'MdetailsCtrl',
        resolve: loadSequence('MdetailsArgs')
    })
    .state('app/shops', {
        url: '/app/shops/:id',
        templateUrl: 'templates/merchant/details.html',
        prefetchTemplate: false,
        controller: 'MdetailsCtrl',
        resolve: loadSequence('MdetailsArgs')
    })
```

and when i force the wrong page to refresh, Check the network section of the Google browser, Files that need to be loaded are loaded in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you are missing dependency files for one of your providers. It can also mean that they are out of sync(order) But i think your dist is missing a js file or something that goes with the providers that you are injecting. If you click on the link in the console, it will tell you on the angular pages which one it is..

Comment: Thanks ,  I find the problem, in that page, i used one directive file, in this file, I wrote a controller, like that:  controller:  function ($scope) { ... } , But when the file is compressed,  The controller's method is going to look like this : function(n){...}, So , "n" Cannot be resolved, I've changed the code  to: ["$scope", function ($scope) {...}],  Then recompress the file, There are no mistakes

Comment: There is a great plugin that fixes these called ngAnnotate you can run it in grunt of gulp. Its best practice however to write the code the way you just did.